# any idea why running alter column causes column to go from “not null” to “null”?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am mass updating a SQL Server database. I am changing all our `numeric(38,0)` columns to `int` *(yes, SQL Server scripts were created from Oracle scripts)*.

Using SMO and C# *(I am a sw engineer)*, I managed to generate really nice scripts like *SQL Server Management Studio* would.

It all works very nicely except for one particular issue:

For a handful of tables, when I call

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] ALTER COLUMN [columnA] INT
```

it decides to also change the column from **NOT NULL** to **NULL**. That, of course is a huge issue since I need to regenerate primary keys for most of those tables on those particular columns.

Obviously, I have plenty of options using SMO to find out which columns are primary keys and force them to be NOT NULL after or while I am updating the data type, but I am really curious as to what can be causing this.

Regards,

Eric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the absense of `NOT NULL`, the default is NULL.

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] 
   ALTER COLUMN [columnA] INT NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

from [ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

> When you create or alter a table with
>   the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE
>   statements, the database and session
>   settings influence and possibly
>   override the nullability of the data
>   type that is used in a column
>   definition. We recommend that you
>   always explicitly define a column as
>   NULL or NOT NULL for noncomputed
>   columns.

Comment: Also from the alter column section - ANSI null defaults are always on for ALTER COLUMN; if not specified, the column is nullable.

Comment: you are correct. After closer examination ALL my altered columns had be reset to nullable. It turned out to be such an easy fix. Thanks for the help.